# Running a Thread every time OnCreate is called

Tags: android

I am attempting to run the following thread every time my activity is created. It works the first time but if I press the back button and try to navigate to the activity again it always crashes the second time. How can I make sure that this thread is run successfully every time?

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                        try {
                            URL url = new URL(priceRangeLargeImageString[i]);
                            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                            connection.setDoInput(true);
                            connection.connect();
                            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                            largeImage.add(bitmap);

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("Exception", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    latch.countDown();
                }
            }).start();

                try {
                    latch.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                addtoView();
```

My thread is populating an ArrayList that I am putting into a custom adapter here:

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.forlist, parent, false);

    }

  //  parent.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

    TextView address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Address);
    address.setText(flowername.get(position));

    TextView price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);

    price.setText("$" + flowerprice.get(position), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    Spannable spannable = (Spannable) price.getText();
    spannable.setSpan(STRIKE_THROUGH_SPAN, 0, price.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    TextView discount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.discountPrice);

   discountedPrice = Double.parseDouble(flowerprice.get(position)) / 1.15;
   String priceString = new DecimalFormat("$##.00").format(discountedPrice);
    discount.setText(priceString);

    TextView size = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sizes);
    size.setText(flowersize.get(position));

    final ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flowerImage);
    image.setImageBitmap(flowerimage.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

My logcat is the following:

03-09 21:33:01.540  18890-18890/com.example.andrewberkowitz.bae W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41862da0)
03-09 21:33:01.550  18890-18890/com.example.andrewberkowitz.bae E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.andrewberkowitz.bae, PID: 18890
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
            at com.example.andrewberkowitz.bae.FlowerShopAdapter.getView(FlowerShopAdapter.java:106)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2780)
            at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1274)
            at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1186)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5398)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5398)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5398)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5398)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5398)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17594)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2308)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1409)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1610)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1267)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6638)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-09 21:33:01.830  18890-19449/com.example.andrewberkowitz.bae D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 792K, 31% free 19230K/27848K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
03-09 21:33:02.201  18890-19449/com.example.andrewberkowitz.bae D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 83K, 25% free 21018K/27848K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
03-09 21:33:02.381  18890-19449/com.example.andrewberkowitz.bae D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 30K, 22% free 21923K/27848K, paused 22ms, total 22ms

Comment: If largeImage is an Array or HashMap, you'll need to synchronize access to it so that multiple threads can't call add() at the same time.

Comment: latch makes sure that my addtoView() method isn't call until after the tread executes.

Comment: largeImage is an ArrayList

Comment: show your logcat where the app crash. I think you need to stop it or destroy it first before you call again because your thread will run separately from your UI Thread

Comment: Post your code where you start this thread and also your logcat

Comment: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0` this is your problem. Your ArrayList is empty at this point.

Comment: mr.icetea correct, but the reason that is happening is because my thread doesn't run the second time. I am trying to figure out how to make sure the thread is run every time my activity is created.

Answer (score 0):

onCreate is not called if you navigate back to an already created activity.

try moving your code into onResume():

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(priceRangeLargeImageString[i]);
                        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        connection.setDoInput(true);
                        connection.connect();
                        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                        largeImage.add(bitmap);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("Exception", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
                latch.countDown();
            }
        }).start();
}
```

Comment: The problem is not that the thread isn't being called the second time it's that it doesn't work when it is called the second time.